# Start on Item Creation is Always True

Tags: workflow

In my workflow I want to send two different e-mails based on how the workflow is started.

I'm checking whether Association:Start on Item Change or Association:Start on Item Creation equal to 'Yes' but the workflow always executes the actions in the Creation block even if I edit the item to trigger the workflow.

Am I mistaken to use these parameters for this purpose? Or is something wrong with my Sharepoint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have a workflow that fires on creation and change, I typically need some sort of value to do an evaluation on in the foirst step of the workflow.  This could be a hidden status column or a field with a default value.

Then based on the value of that column, I go down different trees of the workflow.

Comment: +1 for simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

The settings you reference check the current workflow to see if it is configured to run on Item Change or Item Creation, not what context it is actually running in.  If you want the workflows to do different things, then I would create one workflow for create and one for change.

Comment: I agree that's also an option but the duplicated part in two workflows are rather large and I don't really want to do that.